# Why is my break statement only working on the first "if"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a prompt based todo list

At the moment I'm trying to add the part that will prompt the user to add to the array, which works, but then when I try to quit it just keeps asking.
Quit works on the first question - "What would you like to do?" but once I've said "new" then typed an item it won't let me quit.

```js
// TO DO 
let toDo = [];

let options = prompt("What would you like to do?")
while (options !== "quit") {
  if (options === "quit") {
    break;
  }
  if (options === "new") {
    let options = prompt("add to do")
    toDo.push(options);
  }
}

console.log( toDo )
```

Comment: *"m trying to do it with as little copying or finding the answers myself as possible..."* I don't think that's really what you meant to say. You don't want to try to find the answers yourself?

Comment: What scope do you think the inner `let options` has?

Comment: Don’t redeclare `let options`?

Comment: `let` is scoped on the code block and you're creating a new `options` variable. The `options` variable in the while is a different variable and never gets updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `break` here is completely pointless. `if (options === "quit") {` will never pass because `while (options !== "quit") {` will have failed by that time.

Your problem is caused because you have **two** variables named `options`.

The first one (on line 4) is used to test if the loop should exit or not.

The second one (inside `if (options === "new") {`) is used to push something onto the `toDo` array and [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the first one.

**Don't redeclare** `options`. Remove `let` from the second one and just assign a new value to the **existing** variable.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code, what you do wrong,

1. you declare options again
2. if (options === "new") if bad, it make an infinite loop when the value is not 'new' (or 'quit')
3. the while test is sufficient

```js
// TO DO 
let toDo = []

let options = prompt("What would you like to do?")
while (options !== "quit")
  {
  toDo.push(options)
  options = prompt("add to do")
  }

console.log( toDo )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your logic, using just one prompt; when users click on `OK` the input will be added to the to-do list and when they click on `Cancel` you will stop prompting the user for input.

Furthermore, as you have to prompt the user *at least once*, it would make sense to use a `do { ... } while ()` block.

```js
const todoList = [];
let todoItem;

do {
  todoItem = window.prompt('What do you want to add to your list?\n(click on "OK" to add an item or on "Cancel" to quit)');
  
  if (todoItem !== null && todoItem !== '') todoList.push(todoItem)
} while (todoItem !== null)

// test
console.log(todoList);
```